# Inductively defined dense vector lemmas

Tags: coq

Inspired by another question on StackOverflow, I defined a *dense vector* to be a vector with `option A` type elements that only contains `Some _` elements, and no `None` elements.

```
Require Import Vector.
Section Dense.
  Variable A:Type.

  Inductive Is_dense : forall n, t (option A) n -> Prop :=
  | snil : Is_dense 0 (nil _)
  | scons: forall n s, Is_dense n s -> forall a, Is_dense (S n) (cons _ (Some a) _ s).
```

How can I prove the following two lemmas?

```
  Lemma Is_dense_tl: forall n (s: t (option A) (S n)),
                     Is_dense (S n) s -> Is_dense n (tl s).
```

and

```
  Lemma dense_hd: forall n (s: t (option A) (S n)), Is_dense (S n) s -> A.
```

And also, in the first lemma, when I do `inversion s.` I get the elements `h n' X` that were used by `s`'s constructor, but how can I get an equality stating `s = cons (option A) h n' X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of type dependency, `inversion` can't directly generate what you expect, because it is not true in general. However, it is true for a large family of types, whose equality is *decidable*. In your case, you can apply `Eqdep_dec.inj_pair2_eq_dec` to get the equality you want, if you provide the fact that equality upon `nat` is decidable (and it is).

Here is the proof for the first lemma:

```
Lemma Is_dense_tl: forall n (s: t (option A) (S n)),
                     Is_dense (S n) s -> Is_dense n (tl s).
Proof.
intros n s hs.
inversion hs; subst; clear hs.
apply Eqdep_dec.inj_pair2_eq_dec in H0.
- now rewrite <- H0; simpl.
- (* insert proof of decidablity *) admit.
Qed.
```

EDIT: About your comment about the second lemma.

The main difference between your two lemmas is that the first one tries to prove the property `Is_dense n (tl s)` which lives in `Prop`, whereas the second one tries to exhibit a term of type `A`. In short, the former creates a term of sort `Prop`, the latter a term of sort `Type`.

To avoid inconsistency in Coq's logic, there is a *hierarchy* to organize the sorts, which is (not exactly, but to give you the rough idea) `Prop: Set` `Set:Type_0` and `Type_n: Type_n+1`. On top of this hierarchy is built a type system where the dependent pair (e.g. the type `{n: nat | even n }` is the type of even natural numbers) is restricted. You can build a `Prop` from other `Prop` (e.g. `forall p:Prop, p -> p` lives in `Prop`). However you need to be careful when `Type` is involved.  For example, (again, please refer to Coq's documentation for the exact statement) `forall n:Type_i, Type_j` is of type `Type_max(i,j)`.

This restriction is here to avoid inconsistency (like Russel's paradox) in Coq's type system.

In your case, you are trying to inspect (using `inversion`) a term of sort `Prop` (`Is_dense (S n) s`) to build a term of type `A`, of sort `Type`. This is forbidden by the type system. To build a term of sort `Type`, you need to inspect terms of at least the sort `Set`. In your example, all you have to do is change the definition of `Is_dense` to land in `Type` instead of `Prop`, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks!  It needed a decidability proof for `nat`, rather than for `A`, so that was easy, using `Arith.Peano_dec.eq_nat_dec.`   However, when I try to use `inversion hs.` for the second lemma, I get the error `Error: Inversion would require case analysis on sort 
Type which is not allowed for inductive definition Is_dense.`  Why is it possible to use inversion in the first lemma but not in the second?

Comment: After changing `A` from `Type` to `Set`, and chaning `Is_dense ...` from `Prop` to `Set` I was able to do `inversion hs.` in the second lemma.  What happened?  Is there a less drastic solution (than changing the definitions)?